# Excel formula to display ONLY month and year?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Looking for an excel formula that will display "13-Aug" and means August of 2013. I would ideally want to copy the "13-Aug" cell to the 11 cells on its right, incrementing the month and appropriate year each time, so it would look like:

"13-Aug", "13-Sep", ..., "13-Dec", "14-Jan", "14-Feb"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a number of ways to go about this. One way would be to enter the date `8/1/2013` manually in the first cell (say `A1` for example's sake) and then in `B1` type the following formula (and then drag it across):

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)+1,1)
```

Since you only want to see month and year, you can format accordingly using the different custom date formats available.

The format you're looking for is `YY-Mmm`.

Comment: the custom format is an important step if you want to use it in charts etc

Answer (score 9):

Try the formula

```
=TEXT(TODAY(),"MMYYYY")
```

Comment: While showing the month and year, this one didn't work for me because it cannot be sorted as expected.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first. set the column in which you are working in by clicking on format cells->number-> date and then format e.g Jan-16 representing Jan, 1, 2016.
and then apply either of the formulas above.

Answer (score -1):

Very easy, trial and error. Go to the cell you want the month in. Type the Month, go to the next cell and type the year, something weird will come up but then go to your number section click on the little arrow in the  right bottom and highlight text and it will change to the year you originally typed